# A grammar question from one-simple-question

Tags: grammar, verbs

We use "be made of" when we talk about wine.

Then can you analyze this sentence?

> Wine is made of grapes.

What I mean analyze is like

I /am/ a student
Subject/Verb/Complement

Have a good day!

P.S. I am a Korean student, so my question itself may have gramatical problems... hope you'll just understand my meaning :)

Comment: I suppose you could say it's S-P-C (P=predicator, i.e. the verb). But bear in mind that "made of grapes" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "is", so the 'real' analysis is more complicated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to edit it. What do you want as a result of analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand your question but I will try and explain the difference between the two statements you are likening.

> Wine is made of grapes.
>
> John is a student.

These are **not** the same. The first is stating an *attribute* of wine (that it is made of grapes); the second is stating something that John *is*.

You cannot compare the structure of these sentences as they are different. To compare them properly, consider:

> John is made of atoms.
>
> Wine is a drink.

These have the same structure as your original examples because now we are stating an attribute of the person and stating what wine *is*.